Calculating covariance where expected value diverges
Let's say we have 2 random variables X and Y with joint PDF:
$$
\begin{equation}
f(x, y)=
    \begin{cases}
        1 & \text{if } 0 < |y| < x < 1, \\
        0 & \text{otherwise. }
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
Let's define random variables $U = \frac{X}{Y}, V = -Y$.
Calculate $\mathsf{Cov}(U,V)$.
My approach:
$\mathsf{Cov}(U,V) = \mathsf{Cov}(\frac{X}{Y},-Y) = \mathbb{E}[\frac{X}{Y}(-Y)] - \mathbb{E}[\frac{X}{Y}].\mathbb{E}[-Y] = \mathbb{E}[-X] - \mathbb{E}[\frac{X}{Y}].\mathbb{E}[-Y]$
Which equals in terms of integrals:
$$\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{-x}^{x}(-x)\mathrm dy \mathrm dx} - \left(\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{-x}^{x}\frac{x}{y}\mathrm dy \mathrm dx}\right).\left(\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{-x}^{x}(-y)\mathrm dy \mathrm dx}\right)$$
The issue though is, that expectation of X/Y diverges here, on the other hand expectation of (-Y) is $0$. Is it appropriate here using convention $\infty . 0 = 0$? The integral on the left side, i.e. expectation of -X is equal to $-\frac{2}{3}$. This leaves us with covariance equal to: $-\frac{2}{3}$.
My question is, provided I calculated this correctly is this approach correct?
Also, if my calculation is wrong somewhere I would like to know if in general this is the right approach, or rather we say covariance is not defined in this case?
Thanks.

I did not go through the calculations, but if the expectation of a random variable $Z$ is not defined, then the covariance of $Z$ with any variable cannot be defined. $\operatorname{Cov}(Z,Y)$ is only defined for the case when $Z$ and $Y$ have finite second moments.

@ultralegend5385 got it, thanks. Then it's very probable I've made mistake somewhere because this is standard exercise and there was no question of existence of covariance.
